# React Navigation - Unable to resolve "./GestureHandlerRootView"

Tags: react-native, expo

При попытке добавить в мое expo react-native приложение компонент из библиотеки reac-navigation

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

Генерируется ошибка:

```
Unable to resolve "./GestureHandlerRootView" from "node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\GestureHandler.js"
```

GestureHandlerRootView по указанному пути не существует, хотя необходимые пакеты все установлены. Та же ошибка вылазит при попытке создать новый проект через expo-cli, выбрав не пустой проект, а заготовку с табами.

Comment: Хорошо бы указывать версию библиотеки при возникновении подобных проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была такая проблема: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/941.

Но в версии 1.5.5 поправили.